# I can't click link inside focus div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Why I can't click this link inside `:focus`? The link always immediately closed when I try to click them.

If possible, I prefer to use only CSS, but if someone can give tips with simple Javascript or jQuery, that's would be great.

This is my code:

```css
.ourservices{text-align:center;background-color:grey;padding:3%}
.cont{width:20%;background-color:white;display:inline-block;padding:1%;margin:1%;cursor:pointer;float:left}
.cont:focus{width:40%}
.cont a{display:none;text-decoration:none;color:black;font-weight:700}
.cont a:hover{color:white}
.cont:focus a{display:inline-block}
.cont img{width:100%}
.cont:focus img{width:100%}
.cont p{display:none;width:90%}
.cont:focus p{display:inline-block}
.kirig{width:100%;display:inline-block}
.cont:focus > .kirig{width:50%;float:left}
.kirig img{float:left}
.kirip{width:50%;display:inline-block}
.more{background-color:white;margin:0 auto;border:2px solid grey;display:inline-block;padding: 2% 3%;margin:5%}
.more:hover{background-color:gray;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}
.clearfix{clear:both}
```

```html
<div class="ourservices">
<div class="cont kiri" tabindex="0">

<div class="kirig">
<img border="0" src="http://www.mo2properties.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/click-here-pointer-md.png" />
</div>

<div class="kirip">
<p>click read more click read more click read more</p>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
<span class="more">
Read More
</span>
</a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link "Read more" is expanded when `<div class="cont">` have focus. When you click on "Read more", your div loose focus and "Read more" is hide

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.kirig').click(function(){
    $('.kirip').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. When providing answers you should do more than just plop some code into an answer block. Explain your code so that the OP and future readers will understand the solution. SO is all about making people better developers through education, not cheat sheets.